# Why does master Qui-Gon think Anakin is the "chosen one" while others do not?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In the movie **"Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace"** why does **master Qui-gon** think **Anakin Skywalker** is the "**chosen one**", even though other jedi masters disagree? Since he promises to Obi-Wan to train him, all the problems occur.

**Note**: Is there really a chosen one in Star Wars? If there is, then who?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess Qui-Gon thinks that Anakin is the chosen one because:

- He was conceived without a father, possibly from the Force itself.
- He has a high concentration of midi-chlorians (more than Yoda).
- His high skill level at doing things most humans can't do (especially given his young age)

The other Jedi Masters find Anakin filled with the fear of losing his mother (which Yoda says can lead to the Dark Side), so they want to decline Qui-gon's request of training Anakin.

I think that's a matter of point of view: Qui-Gon is optimistic, the Council is pessimistic.

I think that Qui-Gon had the confidence to teach Anakin in the Light Side of the Force, hoping to help Anakin control (or destroy) the fear that he feels.

In *Return of the Jedi*, at the end when Anakin (now Darth Vader) destroys the Emperor, making the Jedi prophecy come true, thus it would seem he really was the chosen one.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darth_Vader#Prequel_trilogy

Comment: For the record, Yoda grudgingly admits that he *might* be the chosen one.

Answer (score 0):

Darth Plagueis the Wise, could alter the midichlorians to "create life".
His "student" learned all his secrets before he "killed" him in his sleep.

Anikin had no father, Shmi "could not explain it".

Sidious KNEW of the prophecy of the "chosen one" who would bring order. Even if the Jedi had successfully hidden the story, in the past, Sidious could have heard it from Duku, who would have known all about it.

The same way he planned to have the clone army ready in advance.
The same way he had the droid army attack his own planet.
He, or his master Plagueis, could have altered Shmi's body to cause her to have Anikin, And WAITED for him to mature. THere could possibly even be OTHERS, in case of a freak podracing accident or something.

Anikin was then dropped in front of them on purpose.
Sidious and Vader used a faulty hyperdrive in the future as well, to  limit people's range of travel. Steering someone to a desert for repairs is easy when it is the only planet that "happens to be in range" when the hyperdrive goes out.

With only ONE PERSON (Watto) having parts for their ship, Common on Naboo but not many other places, it was easy to see where they would go.
I'm sure convincing Gardulla the Hutt who to sell the two slaves to was easy as well.  I do find it strange though that Toydarians and Hutts BOTH being IMMUNE to force persuasion, they were chosen to watch over the two slaves. Sidious Could however have use money or power to influence the Hutts.

Sidious, being strong enough to keep the ENTIRE Jedi Council from knowing he was force-sensitive, could have easily influences people close to the Hutts to indirectly influence them as well.

Immediately making friends with Anikin was NOT just grasping at an opportunity, it was pre-planned! Yoda was aware of some forms of dishonesty in close proximity   (watch his facial expressions when Sidious is talking!) but was still clouded from knowing exact intent. Anikin was "groomed" well away from watchful eyes and ears. And was made to APPEAR to be the chosen one. Sidious influenced Kenobi enough to make him want to help Anikin. Sidious probably used SOME influence on members of the council to make them doubt Anikin as well, JUST TO MAKE Kenobi more determined to train him.

Answer (score 0):

In a simpler perspective, Jedi use The Force to analyze as if it were a sixth sense to them.

They analyzed the hard data (midi-chlorians count) and then they analyzed Anakin through The Force. Put yourself in a skin of a Jedi Master which is able to perceive a person's fears, desires and somewhat foresee part of that person's future... Suppose that after your analysis you perceived:

- deep fear of loss;
- strong attraction to a teenage queen that he just met;
- deep desire to become a powerful Jedi;
- cocky and vindictive attitude;
- a future shrouded in uncertainty...

Would you place him as the next candidate for "the one that brings balance to The Force"?

Maybe if you got the chance to know him sightly better in a short time, for example: if you were stuck in a desert planet and he'd win one huge bet for you and allowed you and your VIP friends to get out of there, perhaps you would consider the possibility...

However, besides the Jedi Masters, others at that time may had already perceived the abnormal concentration of The Force in Anakin, namely [Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chosen_one#History_of_the_Chosen_One) (a Sith who supposedly created Anakin by accident - **non-[canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon)**) and the [Father](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Father_%28Mortis%29/Legends) (a being in the Clone Wars episodes that was once a [Celestial](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Celestial) - canon).